# Joomla 2.5 JHTML select to links?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In Joomla 2.5 I have this mod_joomanager_search.php. Do you know what I change in this parameter to get from a select drop down list to standard text links? I cannot find this in the Joomla API:

This is the code:

```
echo JHTML::_( 'select.genericlist', $resul, 'dropdownsearch['.$searchField->id.']' ,
'size="1" style="margin-top:2px;width:100%;" class="inputbox" ', 'value','text').'</div>';
```

Additionally, does anyone know where the API for this JHTML to get a list of all possible options? I keep getting lost on their API pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc for JHtmlSelect is here: http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/HTML/JHtmlSelect.html. The genericlist is part of it.

If you want to create a list standard text links, you don't have to use JHtmlSelect. This class is meant to create select lists as the name suggests :-)
You would just use `foreach` and create the links yourself.

Comment: Here is an updated link http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/HTML/JHtmlSelect.html

Comment: Updated the answer with the up-to-date link :)